# non-existent div error with generated div IDs

Tags: reactjs, dygraphs

I need to generate divs on-the-fly which will contain dygraphs. However with the code below I am getting the dreaded non-existent div error from dygraphs at compile time. If I hard-code "Chart_0" as shown (div ID and dygraph target) everything works well.

How do I time this correctly in react? I have no idea of knowing how many divs and charts will be needed at compile time, this has to be decided at run time.

Going by the console.log() statements in the code, in the javascript console I see:

```
render() chart = Chart_0
PlotCharts.js:32 componentDidMount() chart = Chart_0
```

so the div is being created and id'd *before* the dygraph, as planned. What am I missing?

```
class PlotCharts extends Component {

  componentDidMount = () => {

    var ordered = {};
    Object.keys(this.props.plots.charts).sort().forEach((key) => {
      ordered[key] = this.props.plots.charts[key];
    });

    for ( let chart in ordered ) {
      // chart = Chart_0, Chart_1, etc.
      console.log("componentDidMount() chart = " + chart);
      let sigList = Object.keys(this.props.plots.charts[chart]);
      sigList.forEach((signal) => {
        let localData = this.props.plots.charts[chart][signal];
        new Dygraph (
          chart, // Chart_0
          localData,
          {
            labels: ["MessageTime", signal],
            axes: {
              x: {
                axisLabelFormatter: function(ms) {
                  let d = new Date(ms);
                  let hour = d.getUTCHours();
                  let mins = d.getUTCMinutes();
                  let secs = d.getUTCSeconds();
                  let msec = d.getUTCMilliseconds();

                  return hour + ":" + mins + ":" + secs + "." + msec;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        )
      });
    }
  }

  render() {

    var plots = [];

    let chartList = Object.keys(this.props.plots.charts).sort();

    for ( let chart in chartList ) {
      console.log("render() chart = " + chartList[chart]);
      plots.push(
        <div
          id={chart}  // Chart_0
          key={chartList[chart]}
        >
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        { plots }
      </div>
    )

  }

}
```

Comment: So what is in `this.props.plots.charts` and how does it get populated?

Comment: And when you say `Chart_0`, do you mean that is a string, a chart object or a dom element?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda `this.props.*` is the redux state tree. It gets populated via the usual redux suspects (reducers) and async calls.

"Chart_0" is an example of what the auto-generated ID would be. When I hard-code it into the div ID and the dygraph target it all works just fine. This component does not render until the redux state tree has been loaded appropriately (as per the `console.log()` output).